# How to get ActiveMQ broker version programmatically from a client

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want to get the broker version through broker API available from activemq-client. Is there any way how to do it? I'm on ActiveMQ v5.11.1.

Answer (score -1):

```
> curl localhost:61616 --output -
```

returns some binary output ending with:

```
ProviderVersion  5.15.12
```

Comment: Good point, but does not exactly answer the question (which is about using the activemq-client library).

Comment: The only other way I found was to use the admin console.